# want mysql Auto increment table as Order No- MCI-YYMMDD001 and 001 will start from 001 every day

Tags: mysql

> I Used

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKING(ORDER_NO VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT '0';
CREATE TRIGGER TG_BOOKING BEFORE INSERT ON BOOKING FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO BOOKING_SEQ VALUES (NULL);
```

> I Need every day sequence start from 001

```
SET NEW.ORDER_NO = CONCAT('MCI-',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y%m%d'),LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(),3,'0'));END;
```

Comment: It's really unlikely that you'd actually need to store this.

Comment: okay is there any way in php when user input html data and automatically generate a Order no like MCI-YYMMDD001 and 001 will start from 001 every day

Comment: I guess. Be advised that if your competitors get hold of this then they'll have a fair idea of how many orders you generate in  a day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way...

First, some DDLs...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,invoice_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,public_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

Step 1. Create a placeholder for the order/invoice...

```
INSERT INTO my_table (invoice_date) VALUES (NULL);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------------------+--------------+
| id | invoice_date        | public_id    |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2016-06-06 10:29:29 |              |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
```

Step 2. Update that result...

```
UPDATE my_table a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) total
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON DATE(y.invoice_date) = DATE(x.invoice_date) 
          AND y.invoice_date <= x.invoice_date 
        GROUP 
           BY id
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id
   SET a.public_id = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(a.invoice_date,'%Y%m%d'),'-',LPAD(b.total,3,0));

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------------------+--------------+
| id | invoice_date        | public_id    |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2016-06-06 10:29:29 | 20160606-001 |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
```

Now, insert the next order/invoice...

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id,invoice_date) VALUES (5,NULL);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------------------+--------------+
| id | invoice_date        | public_id    |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2016-06-06 10:29:29 | 20160606-001 |
|  5 | 2016-06-06 10:30:57 |              |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
```

...and repeat...

```
UPDATE my_table a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) total
         FROM my_table x
         JOIN my_table y
           ON DATE(y.invoice_date) = DATE(x.invoice_date)
          AND y.invoice_date <= x.invoice_date
        GROUP
           BY id
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id
   SET a.public_id = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(a.invoice_date,'%Y%m%d'),'-',LPAD(b.total,3,0));

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------------------+--------------+
| id | invoice_date        | public_id    |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2016-06-06 10:29:29 | 20160606-001 |
|  5 | 2016-06-06 10:30:57 | 20160606-002 |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
```

These steps (1 & 2) can be bound into a transaction, such that if step 2 fails then step 1 does too. However, I suspect that there's a way of rewriting it as a single query.